# Etherscan shows transaction from before the contract was created

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, rinkeby

I've deployed a contract to Rinkeby:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x765bb02d0499255e69216c21312ff4bfb62e96e8

The first transaction is dated over 24h before the contract was created.

How is that possible?

[image: Txn list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction you see on etherscan is a transaction *sent* to the mempool and then mined. It doesn't mean there was a contract which *received* it and a succès full interaction  (successful as in some logic is executed, reverting being one of such).

Here, if there was no contract deployed at the "to" address at that time, there is no reason for your transaction to revert/fails, ending up in this transaction "going into the void" (same as what happened with [this NFT mint for instance](https://twitter.com/DrGorilla_md/status/1461846748587044864?s=20) - disclaimer: I wrote this twitter thread)

Comment: Got it! As to how it happened:

1) I created a contract in the Kovan network. 

2) I switched to Rinkeby and accidentally sent a transaction to the address of the contract in the Kovan network (this contract/address did not exist in Rinkeby). 

3) A day later I created a totally different contract in Rinkeby. The sender address was the same, the nonce happened to be the same as well. 

4) Since the address is being derived deterministically from the sender address and the nonce, the new contract in Rinkeby got the same address as the previous one in Kovan.